# MAX_VAL logic violates the rule and outputs 5 > 7 and continues working right after

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, max

Wrote this code to find out MAX num. The code and logic is right but at one step it violates the rule where it outputs 5 as a greater value than 7 and continues working right after. What's the problem here?

```
int main(void)
{
    int maxVal = 0;

    int num[6] = { 2, 1, 3, 7, 5, 8};

    //here is the problem
    for (int x = 0; x < 6;  x++)
    {
        maxVal = num[0];
        if (num[x] >= maxVal)
        {
            maxVal = num[x]; 
            printf("The max num is: %d\n", maxVal);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("The final max num is: %d\n", maxVal);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take the initialisation out of the loop. : `maxVal = num[0];`

Comment: @wildplasser thanks a bunch! it worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following approach

```
int num[6] = { 2, 1, 3, 7, 5, 8};
int maxVal = num[0];

//here is the problem
for (int x = 1; x < 6;  x++)
{
    if ( num[x] >= maxVal)
    {
        maxVal = num[x]; 
        printf("The max num is: %d\n", maxVal);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are always comparing num[0] with the current element num[x] due to this statement inside the for loop

```
for (int x = 0; x < 6;  x++)
{
    maxVal = num[0];
    //...
```